# Download blob file content from Google Drive API in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, download, google-drive-api, blob

I use google drive API to download file in ReactJS:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis'); 

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: 'MY_AUTH' });
const response = await drive.files.get({ fileId: fileId, alt: 'media' }):
const blobFile = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.headers['content-type'] });
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobFile);
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = blobUrl;
link.setAtribute('download', 'downloadfile');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

The response.data is text or binary. when I download a text file, I can open it normally but when I download images or PDF files, I cannot open the file or the file is corrupted/damaged.

Did you ever encounter this issue? Help!!!

Comment: I'm trying to see If I can find a solution but I could not reproduce the issue, do you mind sharing code showing how the ```drive``` object was created?